# Activating port forwarding disables local access

Tags: router, portforwarding

I have a new internet service provider, and thus a new broadband router, a Sagemcom Fast 3890. I have some Raspberry Pis on the inside, that I need to open to the internet, so I've set up some port forwarding. However, when I activate port forwarding, local access is no longer possible.

Example: I configure the Pi on 192.168.0.15 as a web server. I can access http://192.168.0.15/ and see the web page. When I activate port forwarding, I can now see the web page on my external IP address, but I no longer get a response from http://192.168.0.15/ - the request simply times out.

This is a basic Raspbian install, nothing funny. Only thing is my broadband router is new. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: I have the same modem. For now I solved it by Changing to bridge mode and use my router.

Comment: I have the same problem and i haven't been able to fix it. It seems like a strange feature if so. Why would one wanna limit access locally but not globally

Comment: It seems like its only breaking the local access for devices on wifi. If i forward a port to a wired machine and i my self is on wired, it'll work as intended. But if i switch to wifi it'll timeout. Strange thing is that i can ping the device and even port scan and see that the ports are open but i wont be able to connect through a forwarded port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously just the behavior of some broadband routers.